# GitLab CI: Unable to set JAVA_HOME

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running git-lab server with Ubuntu 14 I am trying to compile a build on git-lab Ci but for some reasons I keep getting the same error over and over again:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.
```

No matter how I change the path of JAVA_HOME it is always the same results. I have 4 folders inside the JVM folder:

```
java-8-oracle
java-7-openjdk-amd64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
default-java
```

But again no matter which directory I set the path to it is always the same result.

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
 before_script:
- export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
- export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk"
- chmod +x gradlew

dev:  
  script:
  - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: you need a JDK home where javac exits.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and see if it helps. I had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `.gitlab-ci.yml` to this:

```
before_script:  
  - export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk"
  - export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64"
  - chmod +x gradlew

dev:  
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing `chmod +x gradlew` from `before_script` and move it to the main `script`:

```
before_script:
- export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
- export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk"

dev:  
  script:
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Reference: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2018/10/24/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/#comment-4440925341

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue might have been fixed already. But here is how I fixed mine.

Use case:

After I updated Java on my 3 environmennts(Dev, Staging, and Prod), everithing worked just fine on Dev and Staging. But, for some reasons, the pipeline job in charge of deployment on production kept sending this error: "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_171. Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation."
My JAVA_HOME was set to the correct path.

Fix:
0. make sur you Java_Home is properly set up. Fir windows users, something like C:/your jdk root folder/ (do not add /bin folder).
1. Clear the runner caches in gitlab.
2. Restart the gitlab-runner service on your deployment server.

I hope that could help someone else.